# How to fix bootloop (C5 PRO SM-C5010)but saving USERDATA

Tags: backup, data-recovery, boot-loop

my device **C5 pro (SM-C5010)**, Android 8, Fully STOCK ,**knox not tripped**, firmware: dont know exactly as i am on bootloop but it is **Hong Kong**.

​**PROBLEM**: *I remove cache memory from recovery but then it didn't start , it is in continuous restart bootloop.* In recovery it is also giving ***error "dm-verity verification failed".***

​now i want my imp data safe/backup(including secure folder)as it contains my 7 years of data.. Please someone help **what should i do to save userdata as well as keep knox un-touched..**

**I tried** many softwares like *dr fone fonLab etc* etc , drained its battery completely then charged, alot of Google searches, but bootloop is not fixing neither I get any solution.

Comment: find exact ROM version your device currently is running. download files and flash with Odin3. make sure to use HOME_CSC (instead CSC) do not flash PIT/bootloader or anything that will trigger re-partitioning. i recommend to test on another unimportant device first, until you figured out how exactly to protect userdata while flashing. heimdall may work better